# Extract only one file type with binwalk

Tags: image, extract, png, binwalk

I have a very heavy file and with binwalk I have to extract only one file type (png) and obviously given the size of the file I can not extract all. 
I tried to do `binwalk -D 'png image:png' [filename]` but continue to extract all files.
How can I make binwalk extract only the files I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to use `--rm` :

```
binwalk --dd='png image:png:' [filename] --rm
```

Empty files will still be created but you can just ignore / delete them.